# Early references for discrete optimization

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, ho.history-overview

(Apologies if this is misplaced or too broad.  I'm open to suggestions on how to reformulate it.)

I'm interested in tracing back the "ancient" history of max-flow algorithms, and discrete optimization algorithms in general.  Ford-Fulkerson is my straw-man of a starting point.  What were the significant advances prior to that?  How far back can we go while still being able to make a reasonable argument that somebody was working on max-flow?  How about graph algorithms?  How about discrete optimization in general?

I'd also be happy to get references to places where this is discussed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually, Schrijver provides a good source for history. You can look at the following books and an article.

- Alexander Schrijver. Combinatorial Optimization: Polyhedra and Efficiency. Springer 2003.
- Alexander Schrijver. Theory of Linear and Integer Programming. Wiley 1998.
- Alexander Schrijver. On the history of the transportation and maximum flow problems. Mathematical Programming 91(3), 2002, 437-445. http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s101070100259
- Alexander Schrijver. On the history of combinatorial optimization (till 1960).  Handbook of Discrete Optimization, Elsevier, 2005.  http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/histco.pdf

Comment: +1 for Schrijver.  I added a fourth recommended source, which points to early papers by Frobenius [1912] and Kőnig [1915] on bipartite matching, Boruvka [1926] on minimum spanning trees,  Menger [1927] on his so-called "$n$-arc theorem" and again [1930] on the traveing salesman problem, and Tolstoi [1930] on the transportation problem.

Comment: @JɛﬀE: Thank you very much for the addition.

Comment: Thank you. The last one, on the history of combinatorial optimization, is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Most people cite Euler's 1741 "Bridges of Königsburg" paper as the oldest graph algorithm.  Unfortuantely, Euler doesn't actually describe his algorithm in detail, but only gives a half-hearted example:

> “When it has been determined that such a journey can be made, one
>   still has to find how it should be arranged. For this I use the
>   following rule: let those pairs of bridges which lead from one area to
>   another be mentally removed, thereby considerably reducing the number
>   of bridges; it is then an easy task to construct the required route
>   across the remaining bridges. and the bridges which have been removed
>   will not significantly alter the route found, as will become clear
>   after a little thought. **I do not therefore think it worthwhile to give
>   any further details concerning the finding of the routes.**”

The first complete proof that all even connected graphs have Eulerian tours is apparently due to Heirholzer more than a century later.

- Leonhard Euler. Solutio problematis ad geometriam situs pertinentis. *Commentarii academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae* 8:128–140, 1741. Presented to the St. Petersburg Academy on August 26, 1735. Reprinted in *Opera Omnia* 1(7):1–10.
- Carl Hierholzer. Über die Möglichkeit, einen Linienzug Ohne Wiederholung und ohne Unterbrechnung zu umfahren. *Mathematische Annalen* 6:30–32, 1873.